# Notification on Android

Tags: android-notifications

I'm trying to retrieve the contents of a push notification that I send from firebase, but the problem is that it retrieves me several strange characters, how can I retrieve the data of a notification to show it in an activity ?.
I have this code, but I have also tried using the command intent.putExtra ();

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null){

       infoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);

       for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
           String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
           infoTextView.append("\n" + key + ": " + value);
```